# Problem with changing Array State using React Hooks

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, state

I am new in React and I have a problem with changing states in Arrays States using Hooks.
I have an Array State as u can see below.
How I can change only one cell in my state using ,,setFootballersList" without having to write all of the cells"?

```
const [footballersList, setFootballersList] = useState([["1",true], ["2",true], ["3",true]]);
```

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Please share the desired output. I am not getting what you want to do. What is cell that you are referring

Comment: I give u an example. I have a function ,,changeFootbalers(x)" which should work f.e: for changeFootballers(0) changing state from [["1",true], ["2",true], ["3",true] to [["1",false], ["2",true], ["3",true]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the index of the cell in the array. For example pass it to the handler.

```
const handleStateChange = (targetIndex)=>{
setFootballersList(footballersList.map((footballer, index)=>{
   if(index ===TargetIndex){
     //return updatedFootballer
   }
   return footballer;
}))
}
```